# PHP7 cron architecture for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have some php pages that have lots of queries on them. Everything works correctly, but it takes ages to load the pages due to very large data sets (tens of thousand of rows with compound queries etc.)

I realised I have to optimise this and take it from 30 secs load time to almost 3-4 seconds.

I did some reading on cron job scheduling, and understood how to do it, but I have no idea what the architecture should be in case of a lot of queries.

Example of query in html:

```
<span class="text-muted my-1">Total count of records time</span>
<hr>
<?php
    $select_query = "SELECT SUM(rectime / 3600) AS numberOfHours FROM inf_times";
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $select_query);
                                
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo ceil($row['numberOfHours']) . " hours";    
        }
    }
?>
```

How do I turn this into a cron job (say a cron job that runs every minute)?

**My idea**

I want to display the results of the last cron job that ran, so obviously it's a good idea to have variables for the things I'm displaying in a separate PHP file. These should get updated every minute, but how?

Comment: Create a sperate PHP file. Run that every minute by a cronjob. Save the result in a file, database or something like memcached / redis store. Read from your website out of that cached value.

Comment: Thank you for helping, do I include this file into the file header (i.e. ```include('file.php')``` at the top of each of my files?

Comment: You should only include php code! Read the file / query / keyvalue store where you need it.

Comment: just `SELECT SUM(rectime) / 3600` seems to make a significant change...

Comment: Thank you, but I was more interested in how to actually type a cron job that prompts the server to execute queries rather than a print saying Hello world like most tutorials do

Comment: Before you consider how you can outsource individual tasks to background cron jobs, you should find out whether you have queries that can be improved by simpler means. An additional index can sometimes work wonders... A first step could be to execute the slowest queries with `EXLPAIN SELECT ...`.